# InAppPurchase transactionReceipt environment value in production

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, development-environment

When I test In App purchases and I decode transactionReceipt from SKPaymentTransaction, I see a field named "environment"

```
"environment" = "Sandbox";
```

Can anyone tell me the value from the production?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as far as i know and based on apple [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW3)  .. In Production you will not have this key .. because you are not responsible to do anything with it ,, its just an indication that you are using sandbox when your app will be submitted for production, reviewed and approved, this value will not appear.